# Select All from dropdown list in MVC, using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I m new to MVC,c#  and ws facing some problems. I have a dropdown list in my view which is populated by my database through the controller.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.***ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.***, "Select All", new { onchange = "***Changed()", @class = "form-control", id = "***ID", name="list", style = "max-width:450px;display:inline;" })
```

My page requires me to have a select all button where in if clicked it will select all values inside the dropdown.  currently,from my javascript, i get a single value

```
var ID = $('#***ID').val();
```

and pass it in a print function for a report. The Report makes use of a stored procedure I made in MSSql 2012. When the select all button is clicked it should pass all the values inside the dropdown to the print function. How can i do this? 
Any help or links to a tutorial would be helpful!!! Thank you

Comment: For starters, you need a `MultiSelectList`.

Comment: use `@Html.ListBoxFor` to select multiple values in a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you already have a 'Select All' in your dropdown list (normally with '' as value). 
I think the better approach is to modify the WS (your stored procedure as well) to check the value passed in - so your stored procedure will return all if passed in value is '' in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have "Select All" in the drop down and also want a separate "select all" button - this is slightly confusing.

Ignoring the 'select all' button, you can get all of the option values using map:

```
var ID = $('#***ID').val();
if (ID==="Select All") {
    ID = $("#***ID>option").map(function() { 
             return $(this).attr("value"); 
         })
         .get()
         .join();
}
```

Note: this also includes the 'Select All' - which you can either remove from the selector eg `>option:not(:first)` or handle in the stored proc.

Your button can then simple select the first option in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my goal of sending all the ID's to the print function by changing my stored procedure in my MS Sql Server. Actually, instead of selecting all, I was advised to do this. 
I added this to my where clause
(@ID IS NULL OR s.ID =@ID )

So basically it takes all records where I have not specified the ID.
That is, instead of selecting all values from the dropdown and passing, I select none and get all info into 1 report document.

Explanation here briefly explains what I mean
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp